# Exercise in Polymorphism, Inheritance, and Array-Sorting in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, polymorphism

I'm working on a project for class where I am asked to take a .txt file, aggregate the data into distinct objects, then sort that list based on shared characteristics. My instructions are to make the program able to import up to 200 lines of text.

I have successfully implemented the program to import the .txt file, given a defined array size (if the .txt file has 6 lines, an array of 6 elements) but I need to be able to define it up to 200 elements. When going beyond the number of actual elements, say 6, it throws a NullPointerException. I can't seem to find where this may be occurring as my code appears, at least visually, to handle any instance in which that may occur. Here is where the problem is occurring:

```
public Solid[] solids;
public int length;
public Measurer m;
public int h;

public SolidList(int size) {
    length = 0;
    solids = new Solid[size];
}

public void addSorted(Solid foo, Measurer m) {
    int k = 0;
    if (length != 0) {
        while ((k < length) && foo.greaterThan(solids[k], m))
            ++k;
        for (int j = length; j > k; --j)
            solids[j] = solids[j - 1];
    }
    solids[k] = foo;
    ++length;
}
```

Specifically, Eclipse is encountering the NullPointerException in the while loop in `addSorted(...)`. This only happens if the array does indeed have null elements, but I suppose I can't figure out how to prevent the method from trying to access null elements.

Comment: First of all it is much better to use java collection for instance lists that raw arrays. In this case the size may not be give a priori.

Comment: I'm with Gregory, check out ArrayList -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

You should also just use a Collections.sort with a comparator to do the sorting -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)

Comment: You really should have posted the exception stacktrace. This way people are just guessing at your problem. The code shown does not throw NPE, except if foo is `null`. The stacktrace will probably show that NPE is thrown from within the `greaterThan` method.

Comment: I mentioned below that this is a homework assignment and I am restricted to Arrays. I would love to use an ArrayList and normally would in this situation - I'm just restricted from doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (length != 0) {
    while ((k < length) && solids[k] != null && foo.greaterThan(solids[k], m))
        ++k;
    if(solids[k] == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int j = length; j > k; --j)
        solids[j] = solids[j - 1];
}
```

Might solve the problem. But you should really look into using Collections (look at ArrayList) to handle collections/arrays of dynamic input length.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I'll delete my comment, then.

Comment: I should have tagged it as homework - sorry! This was my first post on here and I'm still learning the rules. I would use an ArrayList but we are restricted to using Arrays for the duration of this class. Understandable, but it makes it much harder. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem. Do you see how the two changes I made (hopefully) fixes your problem?

Answer (score 3):

> I can't figure out how to prevent the method from trying to access null elements.

Check if the specific index of the array is equal to `null` before doing anything that uses it as a value.